# deleting specific member from a node in C

Tags: c

This is messy so if you don't have the time don't bother. I've tried to explain how every function in my code works as best as I could. So my question is the function `Q_drop` which I cannot get working, everything else(all other parts of the code) is working perfectly.

So the function `Q_drop` needs to do the following:

Implement function `Q_drop` that removes the given specific member (as identified by `ID`) from the queue, and releases memory allocated for it. This queue member can be located anywhere in the queue, and after removal, the queue should remain operational, i.e., all the pointers should be updated accordingly. And the My_Queue->last pointer needs to point to the last member.

The function returns 1, if species with matching `ID` was found and removed, and 0, if there was no match, and nothing was removed. Each call should remove only one queue member: if a species is on the queue several times, only the first entry is removed.

So my question is how do I move the pointer to the previous node if the matching node is the last one? The error from checker I get is "My_Queue->last pointer does not point to the last member".

My code:

```
struct animal {
char id[7];  // animal ID: 6 characters + '\0'
char *species;  // species of animal, allocated dynamically
struct animal *next;  // next animal in linked list
};

/* For storing the first and last item in linked list
 * If list is empty, both <first> and <last> are NULL
 * If list has one element, <first> and <last> point to the same place
 */
struct my_queue {
    struct animal *first;
    struct animal *last;
};

const struct zoo {
const char *id;
const char *species;
} animals[] = {
    {"123456", "Dog" },
    {"234567", "Bear" },
    {"777777", "Pink Fairy Armadillo" },
    {"aaaaaaaaa", "Chlamyphorus truncatus" },
    {"666666", "Mosquito" }
};

/* Drops the given animal with animal ID <id> from queue <q>.
 * Only the first instance with matching ID is dropped.
 * 
 * Returns: 1 if something was removed,
 * 0 if nothing was removed, i.e., matching animal ID was not found.
 */

int Q_drop(My_Queue *q, const char *id)
{ 

    struct animal *prev = NULL;
    struct animal *curr = q->first;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(curr->id, id)) {
        if (prev == NULL) {
            q->first = curr->next;
        }
        if(curr->next == NULL){
             //here I cant figure out what to write here tried q->last=prev
        }
        else {
            prev->next = curr->next;
        }
    free(curr->species);
    free(curr);
    return 1;
    }
    else {        
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Allocates and initializes a new queue.
 * 
 * Returns: pointer to an empty queue
 */
My_Queue *Q_init(void)
{
    My_Queue *q = calloc(1, sizeof(My_Queue));
    return q;
}

/* Adds a new member with given animal ID <id> and species <species> to the
 * end of queue <q>.
 * 
 * Returns: 1 if addition was successful, 0 if addition failed. Addition 
  fails,
 * for example if animal ID has more than 6 characters.
 */
int Q_enqueue(My_Queue *q, const char *id, const char *species)
{    
    int n = strlen(id);
    if (n < 7){
        struct animal *new = malloc(sizeof(struct animal));
        strcpy(new->id, id);
        new->species = malloc(strlen(species) + 1);
        strcpy(new->species, species);
        new->next = NULL;
        if(q->first == NULL && q->last == NULL){
            q->first = new;
            q->last = new;
        }
        else{
            q->last->next = new;
            q->last = new;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}

int main()
{
    /* testing exercise. Feel free to modify this function */

    My_Queue *q = Q_init();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(animals) / sizeof(struct zoo); i++)                
    {
        if (Q_enqueue(q, animals[i].id, animals[i].species))
            printf("i = %d, firstspecies: %s\n", i, Q_firstSpecies(q));
    }

    Q_drop(q, "777777");
```

Comment: Did you step through it in a debugger? That's the normal approach, and usually means that you don't need to ask here and wait for an answer

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [clang-analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Well, at this point

```
if (!strcmp(curr->id, id)) {
    if (prev == NULL) {
        q->first = curr->next;
    } else {
        prev->next = curr->next;
    }
```

you have found the node you want to free, but then you do

```
curr = curr->next;
```

before you do

```
free(curr->species);
free(curr);
```

so it seems to me you are not freeing the correct node, but freeing the node after it.  Your code indentation is a bit off, but I think you can just remove that `curr = curr->next;` since you have one later in the `else` portion that corresponds to not having found the correct node.

```
int Q_drop(My_Queue *q, const char *id) { 
    struct animal *prev = NULL;
    struct animal *curr = q->first;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(curr->id, id)) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                q->first = curr->next;
            } else {
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }

            free(curr->species);
            free(curr);
            return 1;
        }
        else {        
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh that was there by an accident, the real thing im struggling with is that if the matching node is the last one @Stephen Docy

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't handle at all the situation where the match is the last member of the list. You should check if the matching node is the last one, (`curr->next == NULL`) and set the `q->last` to point accordingly to the previous node. Also remember to set the `next` pointer of the new last item to `NULL` and check if the removed member was the only one in the list, in which case you can't reference to `prev` and must set `first` and `last` pointers to `NULL`.

Here's little code example:

```
  p = NULL;
  c = li->first;

  while(c != NULL) {
    if(c->id != id) {
      p = c;
      c = c->next;
      continue;
    }

    /* Only member */
    if(p == NULL && c->next == NULL) {
      li->first = NULL;
      li->last = NULL;
      free(c);
      return;
    }

    /* First member */
    if(p == NULL)
      li->first = c->next;
    else
      p->next = c->next;

    /* Last member */
    if(c->next == NULL) {
      li->last = p;
      p->next = NULL;
    }

    free(c);
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Yea that's the problem,but when I write `if(curr->next == NULL){ q->last = prev; }` The checker gives me the error "Queue member 1 is last, but the next pointer is not NULL" but since the condition is that the next pointer is NULL , I don't really understand why this ain't working? @Janne Tuukkanen

Comment: The error refers to the `next` of the new last node. (`prev->next`) I edited the answer to mention this.

Comment: yea but if I write `prev->next = NULL` or `q->last->next = NULL` I will get segmentation fault and other errors from valgrind @Janne Tuukkanen

Comment: You can't use `prev` if there was only one member in the queue in the first place.

Comment: hmm okay then i'm running out of options since I cant use  `curr->next = NULL` either because it's the condition, can you open up a little or do I have to write another condition if there's only one member in the node? @Janne Tuukkanen

Comment: Added a bit of example code.